# Form field value being sent to PHP using jQuery not working as expected

Tags: jquery, uploader

I am using the [jQuery uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) to upload images to my website, it also adds the name of the photo to the MySQL database. The photo name is being added just fine, and I have had a go at adapting some code to add a field called `equipmentID` to the database too, but instead of pulling the info from the `equipmentID` field I just get `$equipmentID` submitted to the database field instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        formData: { equipmentID: '$equipmentID' }
    });
</script>
```

Could anyone tell me, or point me in the right direction on how I can pull the contents of the equipmentID field from my upload form and replace the submitted '$equipmentID' with the actual value of the text field?. What I expected to happen was the contents of the equipmentID field to replace $equipmentID, instead of just the words $equipmentID being posted to the db.

Sorry for the vagueness, im used to PHP, so im not q'd up on jquery at all.

Comment: ALso define "not working as expected" - what was expected, and what happened instead?

Comment: Ok I have edited it now, and added more info

Answer (score 0):

'$equipmentID' as you have it, is a string literal. If you want to get the value of a form field it would be something like this:

```
$('#equipmentID').val()
```

Comment: would it be something like this then ?. formData: $('#equipmentID').val()

Comment: Correct, assuming your form field has id="equimentID"

Comment: That doesn't appear to post anything now, even though the value of the field is 5467557756

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself in the end using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {

    var input = $('#equipmentID');
   data.formData = {equipmentID: input.val()};
   if (!data.formData.equipmentID) {
     input.focus();
     return false;
   }
 });
  </script>
```